# How to get another element from ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, angular-ngmodel, nosql

How to get another element from databse when i have multiple select ng-model in angularjs. Here is my code.

index.js

```
<select size="10" name="ngvalueselect" ng-model="response.data" multiple>
<option ng-repeat="tir in tir2" ng-value="[tir.mapsUrl]">{{tir.id}}</option>

ng-src="{{response.data[0]}}"
```

controler.js

```
$http.get('/tir2').then(function(response){
    $scope.tir2 = response.data;
var googleMapsUlr = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=AIzaSyD8c33WZF24YwooxisG8EWE2KsTPgZH-3U&origin={0}&destination={1}&avoid=tolls|highways";

    angular.forEach($scope.tir2, function(element, key) {
        element.mapsUrl = googleMapsUlr.replace("{0}", element.xout + "," + element.yout).replace("{1}", element.xin + "," + element.yin);
    });
```

And i want to get another element from my database which is corresponding to selected tir.id.

Comment: with this `$http.get('/tir2')` you are getting all the elements tir2 from your API so after this you want to call `$http.get('/tir2/:id')`

Comment: @FabrizioMigotto i don't want to get all of the elements, i want to get one element from my database corresponding to choosen tir.id

Comment: So you have to check in your API methods but is generally used to pass the id as a HTTP GET parameter like this: $http.get('/tir2/:id').then(function(response){
});